# Refresh background colours on dropdown using Converter

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a dropdown list with multiple items and I want them to change colour given certain conditions. Currently it displays correctly when the page loads and the dropdown opens, however if the value of one of the items in the changes (which would change the colour too) the list isn't updated. If the changed item is selected, however, the selected value appears the correct colour (see images)

[image]

This image shows what the list looks like when the page loads and the dropdown is clicked. If i then modify the value using a button (it sets `Val1` for the first item to 2) the list looks the same, however if i select "String 1"...

[image]

..then the item selected changes colour (but remains green in the drop down)

Is there a way that I can get the dropdown to change colour so that when it is opened the colours update?

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TestCombo" DropDownOpened="TestCombo_DropDownOpened">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Background="{Binding Val1, Converter={StaticResource ChangeColour}}">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<Button x:Name="ValChange" Click="ValChange_Click" Content="Click me"/>
```

**C# code**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();
    ObservableCollection<TestClass> listitems;

    byte[] imagearray;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var items = new List<TestClass>();
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Text = "String 1", Val1 = 1 });
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Text = "String 2", Val1 = 1 });
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Text = "String 3", Val1 = 2 });
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Text = "String 4", Val1 = 1 });

        TestCombo.ItemsSource = list;
        TestCombo.SelectedValuePath = "Val1";




    }

    private void ValChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        list[0].Val1 = 2;
    }
```

I tried to bind the itemsource when the dropdown is clicked but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged for your 'TestClass'

Comment: No, it is just a simple class with properties.

Comment: You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to be notified about property changes

Comment: @MojoJojo fantastic, thanks. Working as required now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a quick point in the right direction by Mojo Jojo:

I needed to implment `INotifyPropertyChanged` into my class like so:

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    private int _val1 { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Val1
    {
        get { return _val1; }
        set
        {
            _val1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Val1");

        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}
```

Now each time I change `Val1` the colours change as required.